# Cannot read property of ' ' of null

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a post from a modal. I am getting this error message

> Cannot read property 'CustomerPhoneNumber' of null

everything works fine when I remove the selectedCustomer. part of the ng-models. I need to make it work as is though. Not sure how to make it read the input values.

```
 //Post New Customer
$scope.submitCustomer = function () {
   var data = {
        CustomerId: $scope.selectedCustomer.CustomerId,
        CustomerPhoneNumber: $scope.selectedCustomer.CustomerPhoneNumber,
        CustomerName: $scope.selectedCustomer.CustomerName,
        CustomerFaxNumber: $scope.selectedCustomer.CustomerFaxNumber,
        CustomerAddress: $scope.selectedCustomer.CustomerAddress,
        CustomerCity: $scope.selectedCustomer.CustomerCity,
        CustomerState: $scope.selectedCustomer.CustomerState,
        CustomerZipcode: $scope.selectedCustomer.CustomerZipcode,
        CustomerWebsite: $scope.selectedCustomer.CustomerWebsite,
        CustomerOtherShit: $scope.selectedCustomer.CustomerOtherShit,
        CustomerHidden: $scope.selectedCustomer.CustomerHidden,
        CustomerPM: $scope.selectedCustomer.CustomerPM,
        CustomerAdmin: $scope.selectedCustomer.CustomerAdmin,
        CustomerAccountant: $scope.selectedCustomer.CustomerAccountant,
        CustomerSuperintendent: $scope.selectedCustomer.CustomerSuperintendent

    }
    $http.post('/api/apiCustomer/PostNewCustomer', data).success(function (data, status, headers) {
        console.log(data); window.top.location.reload();
    });

};

 <form ng-submit="submitCustomer()" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <tabset>
                            <tab heading="CustomerList">
                                <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top:5px">
                                    <div style="overflow: auto;height:200px" id="scrollAreaCustomers">
                                        <table class="table">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th style="font-weight: bold;">Name</th>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr><input type="text" placeholder="New Customer" ng-model="selectedCustomer.CustomerName" ng-enter="data.static = true" /></tr>
                                            <tr ng-repeat="customer in customerArray | filter:searchCustomerName" class="pointer">
                                                <td ng-click="setSelectedCustomer(customer);data.static = true">{{customer.CustomerName}}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--End col-xs-12-->

                            </tab><!--End CustomerList Tab-->
                            <tab heading="CustomerDetails" active="data.static">
                                <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top:5px">
                                    <div class="inline-fields">
                                        <label>Name:</label>
                                        <input style="width:150px;margin-left:19px" type="text" ng-model="selectedCustomer.CustomerName" />
                                        <label style="margin-left: 80px">Website:</label>
                                        <input style="width:150px" type="text" ng-model="selectedCustomer.CustomerWebsite" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inline-fields">
                                        <label style="margin-left:1px;">Address:</label>
                                        <input style="width:180px" ng-model="selectedCustomer.CustomerAddress" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inline-fields">
                                        <label style="margin-left: 30px">City:</label>
                                        <input style="width:80px;" ng-model="selectedCustomer.CustomerCity" type="text">

                                        <label>State:</label>
                                        <input style="width:30px" ng-model="selectedCustomer.CustomerState" type="text">

                                        <label>Zipcode:</label>
                                        <input style="width:50px" ng-model="selectedCustomer.CustomerZipcode" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inline-fields">
                                        <label style="margin-left: 14px">Phone:</label>
                                        <input style="width:121px;" ng-model="selectedCustomer.CustomerPhoneNumber" type="text">

                                        <label>Fax:</label>
                                        <input style="width:115px" ng-model="selectedCustomer.CustomerFaxNumber" type="text">

                                    </div>

                                </div><!--End col-xs-12-->
                            </tab>

                            <tab heading="CustomerEmployees">
                                <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-top:5px">
                                    <div class="inline-fields" style="">
                                        <label style="margin-left:49px">PM:</label>
                                        <input style="width:150px" ng-model="selectedCustomer.CustomerPM" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inline-fields" style="">
                                        <label style="margin-left:26px">Admin:</label>
                                        <input style="width:150px" ng-model="selectedCustomer.CustomerAdmin" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inline-fields" style="">
                                        <label style="margin-left:1px">Acountant:</label>
                                        <input style="width:150px" ng-model="selectedCustomer.CustomerAccountant" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="inline-fields" style="">
                                        <label style="margin-left:30px">Super:</label>
                                        <input style="width:150px" ng-model="selectedCustomer.CustomerSuperintendent" type="text">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </tab>
                        </tabset><!--End Tab Content-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <input style="margin-left:360px;margin-top:25px;width:70px" type="submit" value="Save" go-click="#" />
                            <input style="margin-left: 20px; width: 70px; margin-top: 25px" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" value="Exit" go-click="#" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Updated

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'CustomerId' of null
at Scope.$scope.submitCustomer (http://localhost:44301/MyScripts/JobController.js:255:48)
at http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.js:10836:21
at http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.js:19094:17
at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.js:12673:28)
at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.js:12771:23)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/angular.js:19093:21)
at HTMLFormElement.x.event.dispatch (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:22:14129)
at HTMLFormElement.v.handle (http://localhost:44301/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:22:10873) angular.js:10061(anonymous function) angular.js:10061(anonymous function) angular.js:7357Scope.$apply angular.js:12773(anonymous function) angular.js:19093x.event.dispatch jquery-1.10.2.js:9789v.handle
```

Comment: I recommend putting this into a jsfiddle or plunkr.  You are much more likely to get fast help if you do.

Comment: normally I would but I am not sure how to set the POST up to give the same error. Here is the plunkr from a previous question i had help with. It is what i am using now. http://plnkr.co/edit/9SkOWYEQt5dAGPwKbEOW?p=preview

Comment: Your plunker has cases mixed up "customerName" vs "CustomerName", but that won't result in the error you are getting.  The post doesn't seem to be the cause of that error either, since the post line doesn't reference CustomerPhoneNumber.  You need to post more info (again, I recommend a proper plunker) if you want to get accurate help.

Comment: new plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/7pWLFBvoX7TT3BWX1xrz?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is your problem:

```
  $scope.customers = [
    {CustomerName: 'PizzaHut', CustomerAddress: '1234 Street', CustomerWebsite: 'website.com', CustomerCity: 'Houston', CustomerState: 'TX', CustomerZipcode: '77493',CustomerPhoneNumber: '713-987-5632', CustomerFaxNumber: '281-789-2145'}, 
    {CustomerName: 'PappaJohns', CustomerAddress: '9876 Hayes', CustomerWebsite: 'widget.com', CustomerCity: 'Katy', CustomerState: 'TX', CustomerZipcode: '77042',CustomerPhoneNumber: '281-452-8523', CustomerFaxNumber: '713-565-9657'}
    ];
  $scope.customerArray = [];
  $scope.selectedCustomer = $scope.customerArray[0];
```

You have scope.customers which you add your customers to, and scope.customerArray which is just an empty array.

When you select your customer, you are selecting the first member of an empty array.

So change this:

```
  $scope.selectedCustomer = $scope.customerArray[0];
```

to this:

```
  $scope.selectedCustomer = $scope.customers[0];
```

**Edit**

Ok, I see your update, but you still have roughly the same problem.

```
  $scope.customerArray = [
    {CustomerName: 'PizzaHut', CustomerAddress: '1234 Street', CustomerWebsite: 'website.com', CustomerCity: 'Houston', CustomerState: 'TX', CustomerZipcode: '77493',CustomerPhoneNumber: '713-987-5632', CustomerFaxNumber: '281-789-2145'}, 
    {CustomerName: 'PappaJohns', CustomerAddress: '9876 Hayes', CustomerWebsite: 'widget.com', CustomerCity: 'Katy', CustomerState: 'TX', CustomerZipcode: '77042',CustomerPhoneNumber: '281-452-8523', CustomerFaxNumber: '713-565-9657'}
    ];
  $scope.customerArray = [];
```

You initialize the array with data, and then you re-initialize it as an empty array.  You are setting your selectedCustomer to the first member of an empty array.  Remove the second line and you should be golden.

Comment: my fault I didnt change the customers to customerArray. this is how I have it in my project   http://plnkr.co/edit/MdDIDXO9YRaDEBstU3A8?p=preview

Comment: $scope.customerArray should be $scope.customers.  Here is a working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/E7KnPn93COlwxigGhvEB?p=preview